# How to set a jButton to trigger a key event in the keyboard?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

For example, I have created a `jTextField` and ten `jButton`s representing 0-9 keyboard buttons in a number pad.

Here what I want is when I press the `jButton` which represents `0`, it should trigger the keyboard's `0` button instead of triggering an assigned variable value (`int jButton_Zero = 0`) to the `jButton` and then it should appear on the `jTextField`.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger the keyboard's `0` button"? A keyboard is an _input_ device: that is, you press buttons on it and it generates the events, not the other way around.

Comment: Not sure that's what I'd be wanting to do - instead, you might just append the "value" of the button to the end of the text fields text or directly via the `Document`

Comment: After a little research, I solved the problem by using the `java.awt.Robot` class.